# Failing to insert dict object with nested array into MongoDB (pymongo)

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, dictionary, insert

I´m trying to insert dict objects into MongoDB. I´m using this code in a python script

```
result = centros.insert(clinica)
```

where clinica is the dict object

the following value give me no problems.

```
{
    'General details': {
        'CCN': '1046002329',
        'Regional Authorization Code of the Center': '5711',
        'Name of Centre': '+ DENTAL OLIVA S.C.P.',
        'Autonomous Community': 'Comunitat Valenciana',
        'Province': 'Valencia/València',
        'Town/City': 'Oliva'
    },
    'Address': {
        'Type of street': 'CALLE',
        'Name of street': 'MONJAS CLARISAS',
        'Number': '1',
        'Postcode': '46780'
    },
    'Contact': {
        'Email': 'DENTALBENIMACLET@HOTMAIL.COM',
        'Telephone': '962854567'
    },
    'Type of Centre': {
        'Type of Centre': 'C251 - Clínicas Dentales'
    },
    'Classification': {
        'Authority or Organisation': 'Privados',
        'Classification': 'Privados'
    },
    'Care Offered': {
        **'Authorised Services': ['U.44 Odontología/Estomatología']**
    },
    'Administrative details': {
        'Date Authorisation Received': '21/02/2005',
        'Date of Last Authorisation': '10/09/2020',
        'Most Recent Authorisation Type': 'Autorizacion de modificacion'
    }
}

But if I try to insert this one, the insert fails :

{
    'General details': {
        'CCN': '0908000855',
        'Regional Authorization Code of the Center': 'E08034627',
        'Name of Centre': '+ SALUT DENTAL',
        'Autonomous Community': 'Cataluña',
        'Province': 'Barcelona',
        'Town/City': 'Igualada'
    },
    'Address': {
        'Type of street': 'AVENIDA',
        'Name of street': 'BALMES',
        'Number': '30',
        'Postcode': '08700'
    },
    'Contact': {
        'Email': 'SALUTDENTAL@SALUTDENTAL.CAT',
        'URL.': 'WWW.SALUTDENTAL.CAT',
        'Telephone': '938039232',
        'Fax': '938067466'
    },
    'Type of Centre': {
        'Type of Centre': 'C251 - Clínicas Dentales'
    },
    'Classification': {
        'Authority or Organisation': 'Privados',
        'Classification': 'Privados'
    },
    'Care Offered': {
        **'Authorised Services': ['U.35 Anestesia y Reanimación', 'U.44 Odontología/Estomatología', 'U.84 Depósito de medicamentos']**
    },
    'Administrative details': {
        'Date Authorisation Received': '30/09/1997',
        'Date of Last Authorisation': '29/05/2018',
        'Most Recent Authorisation Type': 'Autorizacion de modificacion'
    }
}
```

The difference between them is the number of elements in the array 'Authorised Services'. With one element, the insert goes fine. With more than one, the insert fails.

I´m stacked here, cannot find an explanation.

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further information on how to structure your question to get the best help.

Answer (score 0):

The insert fails because you have an invalid field `URL.`. Field names cannot contain a period (`.`)

```
    'URL.': 'WWW.SALUTDENTAL.CAT',
```